# How to know what packages are available with (home)brew?

Tags: homebrew, package-management

I am new to Mac coming from Ubuntu Linux background. How do I find out what packages are available for [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)? With Ubuntu I could search packages.ubuntu.com for example, or Google since its using `apt`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`brew search` lists all available formula (aka packages), requires you to install brew first of course.

Additionally, if you want to get further information about that package before installing it `brew info <package name>` will list relevant information like version number, dependencies etc.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to install Homebrew first (in order to see all the publicly available packages with `brew search` as [patrix answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33357/1453)), you could browse the **[formulas on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula)** to see which packages are available — and *how* they will be installed.

**Note:** GitHub lists only the first 1000 files from a directory; which is far less than the number of Homebrew Formulae (3111 and counting). You can search for a known / partially known filename with [file finder](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/find/master/) (or press <kbd>t</kbd> when at directory listing).

Answer (score 3):

There is a cool website where you can search for the packages and it will list the necessary command to install the stuff.
[BrewInstall](https://brewinstall.org) is the website.

Suppose you want to install **wget** but don't know the exact name of the package, search the it on https://brewinstall.org it will show you the necessary commands to install it.

Here is how the commands looks like after searching the package:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install wget
```

Comment: `brewinstall.org` site shows up as **unsafe** in [Google Safe Browsing status](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=brewinstall.org&hl=en-US), hence Safari shows me warning!

Answer (score 2):

There is, of course, the online package (a.k.a. formula) browser on Homebrew’s own website: [formulae.brew.sh](https://formulae.brew.sh). You can find formulae (formulas on the street), casks, and analytics data.