# How to search for a homebrew package by URL with `brew` command?

Tags: homebrew

It's sometimes convenient to search for a package by its homepage URL rather than its name.
I found it's possible using the search on [Homebrew homepage](https://brew.sh/).

##### The question is: How to do this with the `brew` command?

I've tried `brew search` like the following, but it seems incapable to search by a URL.

```
brew search https://sqlitebrowser.org/
```

Comment: There already is a QA for this as you can see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33354/how-to-know-what-packages-are-available-with-homebrew)

Comment: @fabolous05
 I wanna search for packages *by its URL using brew command*. Which answer do you see as an answer to my question there?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the ideal solution.  However, after following these steps, you will be able to search for `brew formulaes` by URL.

Paste the following **AppleScript** code into a new **Script Editor.app** document.
*(I named my version "Brew_Master_List_Formulaes_Cataloger.scpt")*

This **AppleScript** code will create 2 text files on your Desktop. *("Brew_Formulaes_List.txt" and "Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt")*

[image: enter image description here1]

[image: enter image description here2]

```
property brewFormulae : POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "Brew_Formulaes_List.txt"
property brewFormulaesInfo : POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt"

do shell script "/usr/local/bin/brew formulae > " & quoted form of brewFormulae

try
    do shell script "rm -f " & quoted form of brewFormulaesInfo
end try

set brewItemInfo to reverse of rest of reverse of paragraphs of (read brewFormulae)

repeat with i in brewItemInfo
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/brew info " & quoted form of i & ¬
        " |sed '1,3!d' >> " & quoted form of brewFormulaesInfo
    do shell script "echo ' '" & " >> " & quoted form of brewFormulaesInfo
end repeat
```

***NOTE: The "Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt" file could take up to 3 hours to be completed.***

Once your "Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt" has been created, you can now search by URL, using the "Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt" as the source.

In **Terminal.app**, change your `pwd` (present working directory) to your Desktop with this command `cd ~/Desktop` (because this is where your "Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt" is located)

Now, for instance, the URL you want to search for contains "advancemame.it/scan-readme.html" (you will get better results by omitting the http:// or https:// or www.), your search commands in Terminal would be...

`grep -ERIhi -B2 'advancemame.it/scan-readme.html' Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt`

The result should look something like this...
[image: enter image description here3]

Using your example URL...

`grep -ERIhi -B2 'https://sqlitebrowser.org/' Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt`

produced no results but...

`grep -ERIhi -B2 'sqlite.org' Brew_Formulaes_Info.txt` returned

[image: enter image description here4]

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew [provides JSON files for all core and cask formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/docs/api/).

So you could install `jq` to use something like

```
curl -s https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json | \
    jq -r '.[] | select(.homepage | contains("sqlite.org")) | [ .name, .desc ] | join(": ")'
    
dbhash: Computes the SHA1 hash of schema and content of a SQLite database
sqldiff: Displays the differences between SQLite databases
sqlite: Command-line interface for SQLite
sqlite-analyzer: Analyze how space is allocated inside an SQLite file
```

If you want to skip on the `jq` dependency and assume that the format of the JSON files won't change

```
curl -s https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json | \
    sed -E -n 's|^.*"name":"([^"]+)".*sqlite.org.*|\1|p'
```

will do as well.